# Как сделать настройку фильтрации массива списка на странице?

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Прикладываю исходник

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FKHa/So2UeNPsa

Проблема в следующем, на странице формируется списки магнитных карт. К сожалению отображаются магнитные карты только за сегодняшнее число. В не зависимости установки даты вручную. Однако в этом месте филтьра если убрать $arFilter, то карты за предыдущие даты появится, хоть и не в полном составе.

`$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("PROPERTY_P_FIO"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);`

Просьба помочь с решением, поскольку не являюсь разработчикам и даже джуниором...

Comment: лично я не собариаюсь качать ваш исходник, просто сделайте `echo "<pre>";
print_r($arFilter);
echo "</pre>";` и скажите что в нем...

Comment: Array
(
    [IBLOCK_ID] => 90
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыл ваши исходники, там конечно ужас, что творится, и у вас проблема не в фильтре, а в самом коде, там у вас в коде есть проверки на время, проверьте там логику, так как сложно все разобрать.

```
if(empty($r['PROPERTY_P_DATE_VALUE']) || $DB->CompareDates($r['PROPERTY_P_DATE_VALUE'], ConvertTimeStamp() . '00:00') >=0 ) {
```

Comment: То что там ужас - не новость =) У клиента был другой разработчик... Но спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: я теперь плохо видеть стал, после такого кода

Comment: Сочувствую, что могу ещё сказать =)

Comment: Да, твоя догадка была верна! Это часть была проблемой. Решение оказалось банальным. Потребовалось убрать несколько строк(помимо выделенной) и подкорректировать странницу, для нормального вида.